# How can I get a Google Sheets Pivot Tables's JSON defintion using Google Sheets API (for python)?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am updating a worksheet programmatically and would like to also update the associated pivot table.  I see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables#edit_pivot_table_columns_and_rows) that I need to replace the pivot table, so I want to get the current pivot table as a json blob so that I can use that as a template.  Anyone know how I can get the current pivot table's json definition?  Thanks!!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the pivot table as a JSON object using Sheets API.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In your case, I think that the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API can be used by using `sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))` as the fields.

#### Endpoint 1:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))
```

- `sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))` is used as the fields.
- In this case, all pivot tables in the Spreadsheet are retrieved.

#### Endpoint 2:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?ranges=Sheet1&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))
```

- In this case, all pivot tables in the sheet of "Sheet1" in the Spreadsheet are retrieved.

#### Sample curl:

```
curl \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?ranges=Sheet1&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))'
```

#### Note:

- In this case, if the Spreadsheet is publicly shared, you can retrieve the values using API key. But if the Spreadsheet is not shared publicly, please use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and/or service account.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

  - You can also test above at "Try this API" of this pate.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  When I use the "Try this API" I get a very sparse JSON:
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {}
      ]
    },
...
}

Comment: @GuyMatz Thank you for replying. About `I get a very sparse JSON`, if you want to remove the empty elements are including in the array of `sheets`, please set `range`. At Sheets API, only sheet name is used as the range, all ranges in the sheet are retrieved. So in this case, the ranges without the pivotTable return the values as the empty element.

Comment: @GuyMatz If you want to remove the empty elements, please set `range` including the sheet name and a1Notation. For example, when the pivotTable is put from "A10" of "Sheet1", please set `Sheet1!A10` to `range`. The endpoint is `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?ranges=Sheet1!A10&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))`. Of course, when you use this endpoint, please do the URL encode.

Comment: @GuyMatz Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.